# jsonconvert.deserializeobject c# array

Tags: c#, json

I can't make it work. Here's the JSON:

https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos

And here's my code:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
    {


        var url = string.Format("https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/{0}/marcas/{1}/modelos", tipo_cb.SelectedValue, marca_cb.SelectedValue);
        //Download do resultado
        var json = client.DownloadString(url);
        List<Modelos> plist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Modelos>>(json);

        foreach (Modelos data in plist)
        {

            modelo_cb.Items.Add(new ListItem(data.nome.ToString(), data.codigo.ToString()));

        }


    }
```

Class

```
 public class Modelos
{
    public string nome;
    public string codigo;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post an extract of the JSON and your model so that we can actually determine what's wrong

Comment: Without your `Json`, there is no way anyone can help.

Comment: @daniel-martins What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The JSON is pretty long.  Here is the link:

https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos

Comment: Your JSON has an outer wrapper object `{"modelos":[...]}`.  You need to change your data model to reflect that.  If I upload the link https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos to http://json2csharp.com/ a correct data model will get generated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your data model does not match your JSON.  Your root JSON container is an object (a collection of name/value pairs, surrounded by braces), not an array: `{"modelos":[...]}`.  Such an object needs to be mapped to a non-collection c# object, as is explained in the [Json.NET documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializationguide.htm#Objects).  And in fact if you simply post your JSON link to http://json2csharp.com/ it will design a correct data model for you:

```
public class Modelo
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public int codigo { get; set; }
}

public class Ano
{
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string codigo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Modelo> modelos { get; set; }
    public List<Ano> anos { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
List<Modelo> plist;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var url = @"https://fipe-parallelum.rhcloud.com/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos";

    //Download do resultado
    var json = client.DownloadString(url);
    var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
    plist = root.modelos;
}
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8jp4CH).